# reading chars from input including spaces using get()

Tags: c++, file-io

Here is my problem.

I have specified size 2 dim array.Each row includes spaces and "!". Let me show it.

```
row size:3 column size:8 

! !!!! !
!!!!!!!!
!!  !! !
```

I've tried to read it and stored into vector < vector < char > >. To do that, I've written the following code.

```
vector<vector<char> > rows;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    vector<char> row;
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        tempChar=myfile.get();
        temp.push_back(tempChar);
    }
    rows.push_back(row);
}
```

However,I got something wrong I dont know why. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems, this code really wants to read `std::vector<std::vector<char> > rows; std::string line; for (int i = 0; i != 3 && std::getline(myfile, line); ++i) { rows.push_back(std::vector<char>(line.begin(), line.end())); }`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to account for the newline terminator.  When you read the first 8 characters, the next one (or two, if using Windows OS) will be the line separator.  You will need to handle that.

A more robust approach than reading individual characters would be to use `std::getline`.

Comment: Good spotting.  I wonder if that's just a typo on the question entry, or a secondary issue.